# show close icon div on hover on text box

Tags: html, css

I have text box. when I hover on it then close icon div should appear to the right side of the div.

I have tried this code. but somehow it didn't work.

```css
.display_close{

}

.show_close_div{
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  height:35px;
  display:none !important ;
  
}

.display_close:hover .show_close_div{
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input class="form-control display_close" type="text">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon show_close_div">X</span>
```

Letter **X** should be center of `show_close_div`.

any help would be great.

thank you.

Comment: `.display_close:hover .show_close_div` this is wrong as `.show_close_div` is not a child of `display_close`, they're siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.display_close:hover .show_close_div` **Replace To**  `.display_close:hover+.show_close_div`

```css
.display_close{
}

.show_close_div{
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  height:35px;
  display:none !important;
}

.display_close:hover+.show_close_div{
  display:block !important;
}

.input-group-addon{
  padding-right: 18px !important;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input class="form-control display_close" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon show_close_div">X</span>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: I want X to be center in div . how can I do so?

Comment: yes.. but when i hover on `X` div then it gets blinked.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.display_close{

}

.show_close_div{
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  height:35px;
  display:none !important ;
  
}
.display_close:hover+.show_close_div{
  display:block !important;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input class="form-control display_close" type="text">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon show_close_div">X</span>
```